# Responsive Design - MVC Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I try to use dropdown menu in my site. But dropdowns do not work. When I open the menu, product menu opens at the same time. "Products" should be opened when the user click on it.

Also, my css code doesn't work for product 1 and 2 beacuse I try to align them centered, showed in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUhO2.jpg).

Can somebody help me please about these two questions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu-items').toggle(700);
  });
  $('.product').click(function() {
    $('.category-items').toggle(700);
  });
});
```

```css
/* nav-mobile */

#nav-mobile {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
  display: inherit;
}
.nav-mobile {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav-mobile-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #777;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-mobile-button:hover {
  background: #111;
}
.nav-mobile-button-category {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #777;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.category-items {
  display: none;
}
.nav-mobile-button-last {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.menu-items {
  display: none;
}
.nav-mobile-menu-logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-mobile-menu-text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -15px;
}
.nav-mobile-menu-category {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-mobile">
  <div class="nav-mobile">
    <div class="nav-mobile-button menu">
      <div class="nav-mobile-menu-text">Menu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-items">
      <div class="nav-mobile-button">Home</div>
      <div class="nav-mobile-button product">
        <div class="nav-mobile-menu-category">Product</div>
      </div>
      <div class="category-items">
        <div class="nav-mobile-button-category">Product1</div>
        <div class="nav-mobile-button-category">Product2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-mobile-button">AboutUs</div>
      <div class="nav-mobile-button nav-mobile-button-last">Contact</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the Result in Snippet, I guess it's working perfectly. If i am wrong correct me.

Comment: Snippet shows correct. I can't test it with tablet or mobile. Should I trust Snippet result? Because I check results in Chrome and it shows like picture that I mentioned before.

Comment: Can we see the live result? Maybe you have other CSS rules that interfere?